# Can I get the location of my stolen iPad mini 2 with serial number?

Tags: ios, ipad

My friend's iPad Air is iOS 7.1 so the Find My iPhone app can't be installed. How can I find my iPad mini 2 stolen?
Can I find with the device's serial number?

Answer (score 2):

Not with the serial number. If you have access to a web browser, you can go to [iCloud.com](https://www.icloud.com/) and find your device through Find My iPhone on there.